# GroovyShell debug script from classpath

Tags: debugging, groovy, scripting, classloader, groovyshell

[this did help me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833213/debugging-scripts-loaded-with-groovyshell-in-eclipse) quite alot for debugging Groovy scripts when invoked via GroovyShell.
However, this still only works, when the script is loaded via fully qualified file name (e.g. file:///home/user/x/src/main/groovy/package/File.groovy).

When I use

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("src/main/groovy/package/File.groovy");
shell.parse(new File(url.toURI));
```

it fails (CompilerConfiguration with debug enabled is set beforehand).

So, my scripts reside in the classpath and have packages assigned. They execute with both (via File directly and via File+Classloader resource) - but IDE debugging only works when referring to it as file resource (relative! so with "wrong" src/main/groovy/ prefix.

FYI - the scripts should later be included in JAR file and entire application will be execuded as a WAR.

Any hints on what I can try?

Thanks and best regards,
Timo

Answer (score 1):

So, no matter what I tried (between File, URL and URI - with and without direct Classloader usage) failed in at least one case:

- WAR runtime (when being in dependent JAR)
- Unit test launched from Maven
- Unit test launched from IDE

Now, the only way I managed for all three cases is now direct usage of GroovyCodeSource:

```
CompilerConfiguration cc = CompilerConfiguration.DEFAULT   
cc.setDebug(true)    
def shell = new GroovyShell(
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(), 
    binding, 
    cc
)

scriptUrl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(it);   
GroovyCodeSource gcs = new GroovyCodeSource(scriptUrl);

Script s = shell.parse(gcs);
s.run();
```

Comment: Since this is running in debug mode, is it possible to run the script step by step?