# Breakpoints not working with GroovyShell evaluate()

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I'm trying to add breakpoints in IntelliJ to debug `foo.groovy` when used like this:

```java
def binding = new Binding();
binding.lineList = [list1];
binding.count = 5;

def shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
def result = shell.evaluate(new File("../../not-src-main-groovy/foo.groovy"));
```

This compiles and runs fine, BUT IntellIj won't stop at my breakpoints.

On the other hand, if I place `foo.groovy` in `src/main/groovy/com/...` then IntellIJ DOES stop at my breakpoints, as suggested in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833213/debugging-scripts-loaded-with-groovyshell-in-eclipse).

But unlike that post, `foo.groovy` does multiple `import` statements. Those statements reference code from a different github repo, cloned locally outside my project at `../../not-src-main-groovy`.

I've tried changing IntelliJ > Project Structure > Modules > mymodule > Dependencies > + > JARS or Directories > "../../not-src-main-groovy" but IntelliJ doesn't stop at the breakpoints.

How can I configure IntelliJ to stop at `foo.groovy` breakpoints?

Comment: Just follow the link you found and include groovy into your project

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Because my project uses gradle, I added the following to `build.gradle`.

```java
dependencies {
 ...
 compile files("include-me/**")
...
}
```

That way, gradle will include the files in the classpath during the compilation phase, but not actually compile them, since they're not in here:

```java
sourceSets {
    main.groovy {
        srcDirs = [ 'src/main/groovy']
    }
}
```